# Can I tell how long is left on an ALTER TABLE command?

Tags: mysql, replication

On our primary MySQL server, it took 40 minutes to insert rows and re-enable keys on a particular table. On the slave, the `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS` command has been running now for just over 100 minutes, which is very unusual. I'd like to kill it, but that will annoy the slave. Is there any way whatsoever to get a glimpse at how much longer this will take?

Comment: Are both machines the same spec? Under the same load? How many rows in the table?

Comment: Around 16 million rows and a dozen or so indexes, and right now the slave is under much higher load (7 vs .9), I suspect because of this. It does pretty much nothing else. I don't know about the spec, but I do know this taking 100+ minutes is highly unusual.

Comment: if you don't know the machines spec, how can you tell if 100+ minutes is unusual? For all you know it has a quarter the processing power/memory of the primary server. With the exception of renaming tables, alter table commands IIRC a copy of the new table is created and all the data loaded into it. Tuning and storage engine choice also affect the time this takes.

Comment: Because I know what it normally takes, and it's not 100 minutes.

Comment: Ah, so you have done this before, the same change, on the exact same hardware, on the same data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to determine how much longer this will take. The command will copy all data to a temporary table, make the changes and then rename the copy to replace the original. You may well see 'Copy into temporary table' in the ProcessList, but this doesn't give any indication as to how much is left.

I also suggest that you do not kill the process and let it finish the operation.

Patience!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how bad would it be if I did kill the process? :) (I don't need this table at this moment, so I'm not concerned about it; I'm just concerned about the slave's sync with the master)

Comment: In theory, it should not be that bad as the work is done on a temporary table anyway and until it has actually completed, the original is untouched. It is just my personal preference to finish what you start in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

No way to tell. Just have to wait it out.